# Xamarin emulator deploy failed

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm building a Xamarin app using visual studio 2017,I added a button and ran my application just for testing the emulator , I've tried all the emulators and created my own one , they all gave me the same error , Nothing appears on the error list , but a message popup says Deploy failed ,also I've tried to debug on my mobile with usb and the same error appeared, I've tried so many solutions ,nothings changed , any help please?
 [Here's a screenshot of the output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwD7O.png)

Thanks.

Comment: there is a clear error message "apksigner.bat existed with a code 1" - have you researched that?

Comment: Post the log, not the screenshot of it

Answer (score 0):

check if you don't have multiple versions of the java jdk, delete Bin ond Obj folder of the android solution clean and build again, also try to update to vs 15.6.6

Comment: I have jdk 9.0.4 and jdk1.8.0_171
which one should I uninstall?